# how to get xpath of a particular marker inside google map?

Tags: google-maps, selenium

i want to automate a task using selenium for which i need to click on a marker inside google map. How to do that?
When i click on the map I am not able to select a particular marker insisde the map

Comment: Share your code trials and the relevant `HTML`

Answer (score 1):

You can use image comparing trick i.e take screenshot of browser and take marker image then try to find the marker image(pattern) inside screenshot image and return the co-ordinates of where you found the pattern.
Then click co-ordinates via selenium.

HINT: Convert both the images(screenshot & marker) into matrix and perform the above actions